# How to represent this type of FK relationship in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, constraints

Assume that I have two parent tables: `Company` and `Contact`. Assume that both `Company` and `Contact` records need to have 0 or more addresses recorded against them, where the format for addresses for both record types is identical. This implies that there is a need for a third table `Address` where addresses should be stored.

My question is, how can the relationship between `Company` and `Contact` and `Address` be expressed using foreign key constraints, so that things like `CASCADE DELETE` will work? (I'm guessing this means that I cannot have an `OwnerTable` field in address).

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stated:
- Each Company can have many Addresses
- Each Contact can have many Addresses

This also seems to imply that each address can be re-used multiple times:
- Each Address can have many Companies / Contacts

If this is the case then you actually need a link table, allowing many:many relationships.  And n your case I'd have a link table for Company (CompanyID, AddressID) and a link table for Contact (ContactID, AddressID).

You could configure things such that deleting an address deletes all corresponding records in the link tables.  But to Delete and Address if all mapped Companies and Contacts are deleted, that would require a trigger.

If an address is actually only used once, and you expressly want the deletion of a Company/Contact to delete the associated addresses...
1. Again, use a trigger
2. Have a ContactAddress table and a CompanyAddressTable

I'm not aware of any tricks that will allow one table to foreign key to two different tables, and allow both primary tables to cascade delete to the single foreign table.  This is expressly prohibited in SQL Server to prevent cascaded deletes across circular references.

Comment: Thanks, I think that describes my situation perfectly and the approach to take.

Answer (score 0):

Should an auto cascade work if the address is shared? You could use a [INSTEAD OF DELETE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191208.aspx) trigger to implement this special cascade correctly.